# Problem when combining AND and OR operator in search

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to execute the following search on Stack Overflow:

*Give me all questions that are either related to `[rider]` or to unit testing with C# (`[c#]` and `[nunit]`, `[xunit]` or `[unit-testing]`).*

This is my search string:

`(([xunit] OR [nunit] OR [unit-testing]) AND [c#]) OR [rider]`

It returns exactly one result, which confuses me - there are much more questions on Stack Overflow matching these criteria.

So I assume that either my search string is wrong or not supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: SO search is simply not that intelligent.

Comment: I don't think the search function supports parentheses for such logic. You'd be better off using a few `OR`s and then adding watched tags to highlight the one's you want to look at. maybe `[xunit] OR [nunit] OR [unit-testing] OR [rider]` and have [[tag:rider]] and [[tag:c#]] as your watched tags.

Comment: It's much better to use `site:StackOverflow.com` and do a search from the web.

Comment: @Larnu It _does_ support parentheses, just not to that level, and IIRC you need to have spaces around the parentheses too, so `( ( [xunit] OR [nunit] OR [unit-testing] ) AND [c#] )` works as you'd expect, but I don't believe it can do the `OR [rider]` in addition to that.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Do you know whether there are plans to build a more sophisticated search that would support these SQLish expressions?

Comment: It seems to work with `( [xunit] or [nunit] or [unit-testing]  or [rider] )  and ( [C#]  or [rider] ) `

Comment: Awesome @Damien, that seems to give me the expected results  would you please provide it as an answer?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield for general content searching yes, but for specific tag-based queries, no Google is actually not as good, because it doesn't have direct support for classifying questions by tags like Stack Overflow does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the limitations of the search engine, you have to limit parenthesis nesting.

In your case, it seems to work with :

```
 ( [xunit] or [nunit] or [unit-testing]  or [rider] )  and ( [C#]  or [rider] )
```

Comment: Today I learned that imbrication is a word. So essentially... don't nest parentheses?

Comment: @Gimby I am not so good at English. *imbrication* is correct in French ... and the word exists in English. So I used it. *nesting* is certainly more usual. I will modify the text.